# entity framework debug error on stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

i am using EF 6.0 on my project and I add my DB model as a DLL.

when I debug my project with F10, it gaves "An unhandled error win32 exception occured w2wp.exe [6516]"

but when I debug with F5 it runs perfectly. can anyone help with this error.

```
var TourPrices = db.GetNetPriceTransfer(25, 2, '01/10/2014').ToList<NewNetPriceTransfer_Result>();

public partial class NewNetPriceTransfer_Result
{
    public Nullable<decimal> PrivateTourPricing_PricePerPassengerNet { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PrivateTourPricing_CurType { get; set; }
    public double Rate_Amount { get; set; }
    public int ChildType1_To { get; set; }
    public int ChildType1_FM { get; set; }
    public double ChildType1_Net { get; set; }
    public int ChildType2_FM { get; set; }
    public int ChildType2_To { get; set; }
    public double ChildType2_Net { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please add exception details such as stack trace. Also, a bit of the involved code would be nice.

Comment: hi; it doesnt have stack trace. but screen shot is like this. http://imgur.com/J0Yh2CN

Comment: on which line you are getting error???

Comment: on first line.. when i call stored procedure.